# Implementing a 2n-bit comparator using cascaded 2-bit comparators

Tags: logic, verilog, digital-logic

So far I have this code for a 2-bit comparator.

```
module twobitcomparator(xgtyin,xety,xltyin,x1,x0,y1,y0,xgty,xety,xlty);
//I/O
output xgty, xety, xlty; //xgty - x>y, xlty - x<y, xety - x=y
input x1, x0, y1, y0, xgtyin, xetyin, xltyin;

//specify circuit behavior
assign r = (xgyin);
assign s = (xlyin);
assign t = (xetyin);//not sure if I need an xetyin

assign a = (x1&~y1);
assign b = (x1&x0&~y0);
assign c = (x0&~y1&~y0);
assign xgty = (a|b|c|r);//X>Y

assign d = (~x0&~y0);
assign e = (x0&y0);
assign f = (x1&y1);
assign g = (~x1&~y1);
assign xety = ((d|e)&(f|g));//X=Y

assign h = (~x1&~x0&y0);
assign i = (~x1&y1);
assign j = (~x0&y1&y0);
assign xlty = (h|i|j|s);//X<Y

endmodule
```

Does this look good? I wrote a testbench for it and looked at the wave and the outputs were correct for the inputs, but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way.

For the cascading, I know that the highest bit comparator's result (if it is an inequality) will just need to be sent down through the rest of the comparators and that will be the final result. If they are equal, then I just have to find the highest bit comparator where there is an inequality and that needs to be cascaded like I mentioned.

I am stuck on getting them to cascade, I am very new to Verilog and I have no clue how I should get each comparator's result into the next one. Here is my attempt.

```
module ncompare#( parameter n = 2)(input [2*n-1:0] xgyin, xlyin,
input [2*n-1:0] x1, x0, y1, y0,
output [2*n-1:0] xgy, xey, xly,
output xqyout);
wire xqyin;
assign xqyin = 1'b0;

twobitcomparator s1(.xgyin(xgyin[xqyin]), .xlyin(xlyin[xqyin]),
.x1(x1[2*n-1]), .x0(x0[2*n-2]), .y1(y1[2*n-1]), .y0(y0[2*n-2]),
.xgy(xgy[ripple0]), .xey(xey[ripple1]), .xly(xly[ripple2]));

twobitcomparator s0(.xgyin(xgyin[ripple0]), .xlyin(xlyin[ripple2]),
.x1(x1[1]), .x0(x0[0]), .y1(y1[1]), .y0(y0[0]),
.xgy(xgy[ripple3]), .xey(xey[ripple4]), .xly(xly[ripple5]));

endmodule
```

I think I need to use a generate statement since I need to make it work for any parameter n but I have no clue how to use generate since all examples I've looked at only have one output and I have three (that are also the next comparator's inputs! Agh!)

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

The 2-bit comparator module can be rewritten as

```
module twobitcomparator(xgtyin,xltyin,x,y,xgty,xlty,xety);

  output xgty, xety, xlty;          
  input  xgtyin, xltyin;
  input [1:0] x,y; 

  assign xgty = xgtyin | (~xltyin & ((x[1] > y[1]) | ((x[1] == y[1]) & (x[0] > y[0]))));
  assign xlty = xltyin | (~xgtyin & ((x[1] < y[1]) | ((x[1] == y[1]) & (x[0] < y[0]))));

  assign xety = ~(xlty | xgty);

endmodule
```

I have treated the two bit input as a bus instead of treating them as individual bits (Verilog allows you to do that). I have trimmed out the numerous intermediate results that were present in your code. This makes the code easier to understand as you do not have to keep track of all those temporary wires.

I then simulated this module using Icarus Verilog on EDA Playground. The link is here 
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5KRL

A four-bit comparator that uses these twobitcomparators can be written as follows.

```
module fourbitcomparator(xgtyin,xltyin,x,y,xgty,xlty,xety);
  output xgty, xety, xlty;          
  input  xgtyin, xltyin;
  input [3:0] x,y; 

  wire xgty_1,xlty_1,xety_1;

  twobitcomparator u_1 (
    .xgtyin(xgtyin),
    .xltyin(xltyin),
    .x(x[3:2]),
    .y(y[3:2]),
    .xgty(xgty_1),
    .xlty(xlty_1),
    .xety(xety_1)
  );

  twobitcomparator u_0 (
    .xgtyin(xgty_1),
    .xltyin(xlty_1),
    .x(x[1:0]),
    .y(y[1:0]),
    .xgty(xgty),
    .xlty(xlty),
    .xety(xety)
  );

endmodule
```

Finally a 2n bit comparator using twobitcomparators, can be generalised as follows

```
module twoN_bitcomparator #(
  parameter N = 2
)(
  input xgtyin,
  input xltyin,
  input [(2*N-1):0]x,
  input [(2*N-1):0]y,
  output xgty,
  output xlty,
  output xety
);

  wire [N:0] xgty_w,xlty_w,xety_w;

  assign xgty_w[N] = xgtyin;
  assign xlty_w[N] = xltyin;

  generate
    genvar i;
    for (i=0;i<=(N-1);i=i+1)
      begin:TWOBITGEN
        twobitcomparator u_1 (
          .xgtyin(xgty_w[i+1]),
          .xltyin(xlty_w[i+1]),
          .x(x[(2*i+1) : (2*i)]),
          .y(y[(2*i+1) : (2*i)]),
          .xgty(xgty_w[i]),
          .xlty(xlty_w[i]),
          .xety(xety_w[i])
        );
      end
  endgenerate

  assign xgty = xgty_w[0];
  assign xlty = xlty_w[0];
  assign xety = xety_w[0];

endmodule
```

The simulation of this generalised module is also available on EDA playground at https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2fbr
The waveform for the small testbench is also available at https://www.edaplayground.com/w/x/27X